# How to reset phone (DROID TURBO) system settings without factory reboot? System UI has stopped working

Tags: settings, bootloader, system-error, motorola-droid

So, a little bit of background. The worst part about this is that I'm pretty confident I know how to fix it, but I don't know how to go about doing the thing  I need to do to fix it. Bear with me a moment.

So I have a stock Droid Turbo, I don't have any kind of ROMS or any non-play store stuff on it.

So what I did was I went into developer settings on the phone, the "Hidden Settings" and I started fiddling with stuff.

I either pressed on:

Simulate secondary displays
or 
Force RTL layout direction

and the phone's GUI crashed hard. Now it's completely bonkers, and only endlessly loops the error that "Unfortunately, the System UI has stopped working."

Now my question is, is there a way to reset those options in the developer menu somehow, without doing a factory reset? I have a few apps that store local data that will get erased, and I'd rather not.

Additionally, the phone is still working in the background, I can hear text message notifications and it rings when I get a call, though I can't interact with it in any way. The Droid Turbo user interface (For gestures while the phone is locked) works too.

I tried clearing the cache, I tried letting it complexly run out of battery and doing it again. Hard resets. Nothing seems to work.

The worst part is that my PC Doesn't want to recognize it either, which is odd. While in the bootloader it got a connection to my PC as a linux USB Storage device, inside system recovery it made the noise like something is there, but it's not.

So any tips? any way to save my data before I have to factory reset this? I really can't lose that data, a few apps I have store user data locally.

Comment: Is USB debugging enabled or a custom recovery installed? One of them is needed to revert those settings. Which Android version is it?

Comment: @Firelord Yes, I have USB debugging activated on my phone. As for custom recovery, I don't think so. My android version is whatever the newest sweets name is. I wish I could tell you but obviously I can't go into the phone to look right now.

Comment: You mean Android Marshmallow?

Comment: Yeah that sounds right. I'm pretty sure it has it.

Comment: To reset "Simulate secondary displays", use PC and [tag:adb] to execute the command `adb shell put global overlay_display_devices ''`. Note that `''` means blank here (there is no gap between apostrophes). You can replace it with `' '`.

Comment: As for RTL, there is a catch here. I can enable it at will but can't always disable it. You can try `adb shell settings put global debug.force_rtl 0` followed by a reboot. If things are good, RTL should get disabled. In my PA 5.1.1 it doesn't get disabled. I looked around and found that it is a bug in 5.1.1 (may be in 6.0 too). http://forum.xda-developers.com/droid-turbo/general/psa-enable-force-rtl-layout-5-1-t3149244/page3

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I've downloaded the ADB to try and do that and I'm in command line, but It's not finding my phone. `Error : No device found` when I put in `adb shell`

Comment: The error comes up if the device is not connected, or not detected, or USB debugging is not enabled in the device. That I'm afraid I can't troubleshoot for you. Many people have had this issue  in the past and web is filled with solutions and troubleshooting steps. You may have to use a search engine I presume. (Hint: correct drivers; `adb devices`)

Comment: The problem then is that I've already got drivers. I tried the Motorola device manager as well as the Android Universal Device Driver. sometimes when I'm in the Bootloader it'll connect as speedloader quark or something.

Comment: Just an update. If I plug the phone in I'm able to find it when it's in ADB sideload mode, so I guess I need to figure this out now.

Comment: Don't go that way, that would yield nothing. Stock recoveries are made in such way that they would allow you to push some files (in order to upgrade the system) and that's all they do. No shell access would be granted from them.

Comment: So basically I'm pretty stuck unless I can get the PC to recognize my phone. Right.

Comment: Yes. That is true, unless somebody has a better option than the one I proposed. Keep trying!

Answer (score 1):

If your phone is encrypted, the only thing I can think of to get your data is to install a custom recovery, a custom ROM which uses a custom system UI and start the phone. Your data should be there. If it's not possible, you will have to turn off the phone, press and hold power on and volume down and factory reset. This last part is not recommended since you may loose your data.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just install a recovery on an sd card and then install it through the stock recovery mode and reboot into it. The only thing i'm an expert on, is not being an expert, so I might be way off in regards to your Droid. I had to do it on my s5 galaxy and it worked on that.

Comment: Seems fairly legit, to be honest.